# REGEX exclude if there's a dash before number and if inside other string

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I've been trying to write a regular expression that does exactly as stated in the title. I need to find all occurences of xA, or xkA, or xmA (and variation eg. x k A or xk A) to format those amperes later on: x A, x kA, x mA.

Unfortunately with the regex I have it selects number+A whenever it finds it:

F-***2A*** WACEGF**2A**OKR ***10m A AC***

F-***3A*** WACEGF**3A**OKR ***10k A AC***

C-***7A*** WACEGC**7A**OKR ***20m A***

My regex:

```
([0-9]+)([m|k])? ?A
```

I found some solution online:

```
[^- a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)([µ|&micro;|m|M|k|G|]) ?A
```

but it fails while run in Dreamweaver (and I HAVE TO use it in DW, it's part of bigger command) - it "eats" part of the string in the backreference, making eg. "10" out of "1000"

Edited:

```
\b([0-9]+)([µmMkG]|&micro;)\s*A 

(?<![0-9])([0-9]+)([µmMkG]|&micro;)\s*A
```

The first one selects as follows:
[image]

The second one doesn't select anything :(

Note I am trying not to remove the char before the number, i.e. `>` or `/` that are removed if I use the following:

[image]

Comment: Try `\b([0-9]+)([µmMkG]|&micro;)\s*A` but I do not see a reason for your pattern to fail. What is the error?

Comment: There's no error message, string are found and selected, when I want to replace 'em with another pattern then the first back reference looses some digits, making 10 out 1000 or 12 out of 1200.

The code you'd posted doesn't select xA (1A or 11A). There could be `m` or `k` (or other) between the number and letter A, but not necessarily.

Comment: Aha, try `(?<![0-9])([0-9]+)([µmMkG]|&micro;)\s*A`, however, I am not sure about the `xA (1A or 11A)` - that does not look like your expected match format.

Comment: Look at https://regex101.com/r/LcLTS3/1, feel free to modify the test cases to explain what you need.

Comment: I used this site to come up with the longer solution, however as I said, for some reason it doesn't work in DW. Anyways, thank you for your input! :)

Comment: Yeah, you used a wrong pattern, `[µ|&micro;|m|M|k|G|]` matches `|`, `;`, `&` as it is a character class. You need a grouping construct, see my suggestion. So, what doesn't my pattern match? Please add all the relevant test cases.

Comment: I've edited the opening post

Comment: A text would be better. However, I believe there is a problem with the `\s`. Try [`\b([0-9]+)[\s\u00A0]*([µmMkG]|&micro;)[\s\u00A0]*A`](https://regex101.com/r/LcLTS3/2)

Comment: Your solution works on bigger strings, but cannot select anything like digit(s)A, eg. 1A, 100A - https://regex101.com/r/LcLTS3/5

Comment: I will actually solve my problem in two-step action: 1) make spaces and then 2) restore the C, and F names by removing the space in between. Not perfect, I know, but I don't want to waste more of your time (and my company's :D). Than you again for your help - really appreciated! Dziękuję za Twoją pomoc, Wiktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(^|[^\w-])\b([0-9]+)([µmMkG]|&micro;)? ?A
```

When replacing, mind you may access the text captured with capturing groups using `$` + a digit identifying the group. E.g. `(^|[^\w-])` text is access via `$1`, `([0-9]+)` text is accessed via `$2`, `([µmMkG]|&micro;)` can be reached via `$3`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcLTS3/8).

**Details**

- `(^|[^\w-])` - Group 1: start of string or any char other than letters, digits, underscore and `-`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `([µmMkG]|&micro;)?` - Group 3 (optional): `µ`, `m`, `M`, `k`, `G` or `&micro;`
- `?A``- an optional space and then`A`.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)